# In IntelliJ is it possible to map the same hotkey to two different activities

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to assign the same key to both start the debugger and to step into code.

In Visual Studio I am able to bind F10 to start the debugger and to Step-Into code so that I can just use that key for most stepping. In IntelliJ I am having trouble configuring that same sequence.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can do it.

Just go into the Settings (spanner icon), choose `Keymap` and type `debug` in the search bar.

Assign a key (perhaps f7 over f10?) to `Debug` and the same key to `Step Into`. Important: choose to "Leave" the exiting key binding, not to remove it.

It works fine for me with f7, so I imagine it should work fine for you.

Good luck.

P.S. using intellij v12.

Comment: Yes, it's quite a handy feature. You just need to make sure that you're not "double" assigning a key that is used in another context. For example I assigned Alt-R to an action without realizing that it would tick "Regex" when I had the search box open.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that would be possible since, unlike with Live Templates, you can't select a "context" for hotkeys. A hotkey always means the same thing, no matter what has focus. You might try adding a feature request to the [IDEA YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). It's an interesting idea that might get some votes.